# Rails - params not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm building an events app using Rails and am trying to get to grips with the booking confirmation process. At the moment my MVC seems all over the place.

Here's my new booking form for free events which purely requires the quantity of spaces a user requires -

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_booking" do |form| %>
    <% if @booking.errors.any? %>
        <h2><%= pluralize(@booking.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this Booking from saving:</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @booking.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>  

    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Please confirm the number of spaces you wish to reserve for this event.</p>
        <%= form.input :quantity, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>  

    <p> This is a free event. No payment is required.</p>

    <div class="panel-footer"> 
        <%= form.submit :submit, label: 'Confirm Booking', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
 </div>
```

And here's my controller code -

**bookings_controller.rb**

```
before_action :find_booking, only: [:show, :update]
before_action :find_event, only: [:show, :update]
before_action :authenticate_user!  

def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
    @booking.user = current_user
end

def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

    if @booking.paid_booking
        flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
        @booking.update_attributes!(booking_number: "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase)
        redirect_to event_booking_path(@event, @booking)
    else
        flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
        render "new"
    end
end

def free_booking
    if @booking.free_booking
        @booking.update_attributes!(booking_number: "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase)
        redirect_to event_booking_path(@event, @booking)
    else
        flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
        render "new"
    end
end

def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = Booking.find_by(booking_number: params[:booking_number])
end

def update
    if @booking.save
        redirect_to event_booking_path(@event, @booking) , notice: "Booking was successfully updated!"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :booking_number, :quantity, :event_id, :stripe_charge_id, :total_amount)
end

def find_booking
    @booking = Booking.find_by(booking_number: params[:booking_number])
end

def find_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
end
```

When I check the booking on a console, the only params being saved are event_id and user_id - quantity is not saved for free bookings but it does get saved for paid bookings. Also, my booking confirmation show view has the following attributes included -

```
<%= @event.title %>
<%= @booking.quantity %>
<%= @booking.booking_number %>
```

Of these three attributes, only the event.title shows on the page, the other two don't show at all. I'm completely stumped as to how or why this is happening. Would appreciate it if anyone can see something I'm not able to.

Comment: Am I missing something or do you never call ".save" in the booking controller?  I think in that "if" statement inside the create method you would want "if @booking.save".  Or perhaps there is some aspect of your setup that I am missing.

Comment: In the create method?

Comment: yes, anywhere you want it to be saved

Comment: It's a good spot, but why would certain params save and others not even without @booking.save? Why do they save for paid bookings and not free?

Comment: you are sending the data to two different spots, the events is saving but the booking controller is not it looks like, look at create method in events, does it have "if @event.save" in it's create method?  I guess I would need to look at your setup a little more to give a better answer.

Comment: I am not sure anything saves other than booking_number since you are using `update_attributes` for this. All the other parameters are not persisted at all.

Comment: Err, yes it does. So I need to install this and take out @booking.free_booking?

Comment: I've tried using my events controller as a template and I have no issues with that at all so not sure why I'm having issues with the booking controller?

Comment: It looks like to me you want to possibly do an "if else" statement when saving bookings to see if it is paid or free, but this would all be in the create method, not in two different methods.  Again, I am not totally sure about that as I do not know the app or your intentions really.,   Is the booking data saving?

Comment: You are correct I apologize create will save the params because of the `update_attributes` call which in turn calls save but you are not explicitly attempting to save anything save happens almost unintentionally by virtue of your `update_attributes` call. BTW your update method calls save but does not update anything.

Comment: I need to distinguish between a free and paid booking as the app offers both. I have a free_booking method in my Booking model and a paid_booking method - how do I distinguish between both in the controller?

Comment: You would probably want  a boolean field on bookings that is true or false based on paid or free event.  Then check for that when saving.  That would probably be easiest.

Comment: I already have that but on the event table ( is_free? ). I don't think you can have the same column in different tables can you?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same column name in different tables.